# geom_abline() forces y-axis to 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Is there a way to add `geom_abline()` without changing the scales? I've done a bit of digging and haven't found anything that addresses this specifically, and manually rescaling the axes removes the abline:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# generate noise that should be roughly 1:1
plot <- 
  runif(100, 3000, 6000) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(x = value) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(y = rnorm(1, x, 150)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point()

plot
```

[image]

```r
# geom_abline forces y-axis to 0!
plot +
  geom_abline()
```

[image]

```r
# adding in manual scales removes geom_abline
plot +
  geom_abline() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3000, 6000))
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_abline).
```

[image]

```r
# reording when `scale_y_continous()` is called doesn't help unfortunately
plot +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3000, 6000)) +
  geom_abline()
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_abline).
```

[image]

```r
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.3.4'
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: in the short term, I've added a `geom_segment()` that has the x/y limits of the plot as the endpoints

Comment: Just swap the order: `ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
   geom_point()+
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3000, 6000))+geom_abline()`

Comment: OP, adding `geom_abline()` does not reset the axis to 0 for me, so very strange it's not reproducible.  In any case, use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(....))` instead of `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(...))`.  This serves to zoom the plot *without removing data*, so it should not affect the placement of the line at all and you should still see everything.  Seems that limiting the y axis with the `scale_y_continuous()` function removes a datapoint from `geom_abline()` in your case, which removes the line.